# Non-linear QED gauge fixing, writing the effective Lagrangian

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, field-theory, gauge-theory, quantum-electrodynamics, gauge

I have several questions about this problem. I have been given a non-linear gauge condition for a QED theory:

$$F = \partial_{\mu}A^{\mu} + \frac{\lambda}{2}A_{\mu}A^{\mu}.$$

Then I need to write the effective lagrangian. I know that is just:

$\mathcal{L}_{eff}=\mathcal{L}+\mathcal{L}_{GF}+\mathcal{L}_{G}$

Where $\mathcal{L} = -\frac{1}{4}F_{\mu\nu} F^{\mu\nu }$, the gauge fixing term is $\mathcal{L}_{GF} = -\frac{1}{2\zeta} \left( F\right)^2$ and the ghost term is $\mathcal{L}_G = -\overline{\omega} \int d^4y\frac{\delta F(x)}{\delta A_\mu (y)}D_{\mu} \omega$.

Sorry if my questions are stupid but I am trying learn this. So my first question is:

1. With a new Gauge condition does $F_{\mu \nu}$ change? I presume not. So is $F_{\mu \nu} = \partial_\mu A_\nu - \partial_\nu A_\mu$ still true?
2. How is one meant to evaluate the term $\frac{\delta F(x)}{\delta A_\mu (y)}D_{\mu} \omega$ In the Ghost term.
   I know for the Lorenz gauge it simplifies to $\partial_x^\mu \left[ \delta^4\left( x-y\right)\right]D_{\mu} \omega$, which is really easy to integrate afterwards. I belive the result for my given Gauge condition is something like this: $\partial_x^\mu \left[ \delta^4\left( x-y\right)\right]D_{\mu} \omega + \frac{\lambda}{2} \left( A^{\mu} + A_\mu \frac{\delta A^{\mu}(x)}{\delta A_\mu(y)} \right)$, is this correct? If so, how does one evaluate this term $\frac{\delta A^{\mu}}{\delta A_\mu}$?

I believe once I understand this I can answer the rest of the problem on my own.

Comment: Comment to the post (v3): The Lagrangian looks like a _gauge-fixed Lagrangian_ rather than an _effective Lagrangian._

Comment: 2. I meant gauge-fixed I can the rest of the terms to make it effective myself.